# How to merge all unique values of a spark dataframe column into single row based on id and convert the column into json format

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to merge all unique values of a spark dataframe column into single row based on id and convert the column into json format.

Input example :

```
+---+------+-----------+
|id |gender|banner_desc|
+---+------+-----------+
|123|male  |banner1    |
|123|male  |banner2    |
|123|male  |banner3    |
|124|female|banner1    |
|124|female|banner2    |
|125|male  |banner1    |
|126|female|banner3    |
+---+------+-----------+
```

Output example :

```
+---+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |gender|banner_desc                                                  | 
+---+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|123|male  |[{"name":"banner1"}, {"name":"banner2"}, {"name":"banner3"}] |
|124|female|[{"name":"banner1"}, {"name":"banner2"}]                     |
|125|male  |[{"name":"banner1"}]                                         |
|126|female|[{"name":"banner3"}]                                         |
+---+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_json` to get a JSON string from `collect_list(struct())`:

```
val result = df.groupBy(
    "id","gender"
).agg(
    to_json(
        collect_list(
            struct(col("banner_desc").as("name"))
        )
    ).as("banner_desc")
)

result.show(false)
+---+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|id |gender|banner_desc                                               |
+---+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|124|female|[{"name":"banner1"},{"name":"banner2"}]                   |
|126|female|[{"name":"banner3"}]                                      |
|125|male  |[{"name":"banner1"}]                                      |
|123|male  |[{"name":"banner1"},{"name":"banner2"},{"name":"banner3"}]|
+---+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hello @mck, 
We are getting data type of banner_desc as string but we need datatype of this column as Struct() or json type.. How can we get the datatype?

Comment: there is no such thing as json type. If you want struct type, you can do `.agg(collect_list(struct(col("banner_desc").as("name"))).as("banner_desc"))`